# applescript to vbs converter

Tags: vbscript, applescript, converters

Might be an awfully stupid question, since I have no idea if the different functions in APS are the same as VBS, and if the functions abilities are the same in both APS and VBS (Like if there is an equivalent of msgBox() in APS). As you probably can hear, I am not experienced in APS, but is there a converter that converts each scripting language into each other.

Answer (score 2):

There is no VBS, Visual Basic Scripting, converter to Applescript. Applescript is designed to work with applications, so its direct corollary is VBA, Visual Basic for Applications. There is not a converter available that converts VBA to Applescript either (APS is not a proper abbreviation, btw, if the context is clear, it is convention to use AS), however, there are some web resources that you will find. The [guide from mactech](http://www.mactech.com/vba-transition-guide/index.html) is still relevant.

The best idea for you might be to post your VBS/VBA script in a new topic and ask for specific help in converting it to AS.

Comment: Given the syntactical differences between AppleScript and VBScript my guess is that the conversion will boil down to a complete rewrite.